# Sourcetree deleted my files

Tags: laravel-5, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to Sourcetree. I had successfully setup an account and uploaded projects to a number of repositories a year back. Yesterday, updated Sourcetree to the latest version and selected my new project for upload. My project is based on Laravel 5.6 and when uploaded I noticed the repository (browser version of Bitbucket) showed only a selected number of folders. I thought to myself there must have been an issue with the upload therefore I deleted the repository and did a new one for another upload. The same thing happened. I looked into my local project directory to noticed all files were removed and only having the selected number of folders (that appeared in Bitbucket). Basically, my entire project has now disappeared and I am afraid it might be gone completely. Months of work, any help for anyone would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6.

I have noticed a new folder created in the project directory '.git' and within that folder contains a number of files and folders related to git.

God I hope I can get these files back :(

Comment: Sorry to know you lost your work. Loss of work happens to everyone sometime - not just because of sourcetree but for other reasons too!  I dont think files are recoverable. Copy your work directory to some different location on disk. Then find some person good with `git` and let them work on your machine. I dont think it can be solved in a question answer way. Find a real human. Good luck.

Comment: For future learning (1) learn `git` (2) learn sourcetree *before* you hand it over your life's work (3) take frequent backups of your work - copy pasting your work folder is a bad but valid backup strategy.

Comment: I completely agree with you both. First thought, rule 101 always backup your damn files man. I am looking into 3rd party apps to see if I can recover any beyond deleted files on my Mac. I read somewhere Sourcetree will delete at a system level so I am coming to the conclusion for a loss. Just need to be 100% sure if there is anyway possible to get those files. I just don't understand why it deleted my files for the initial commit and push to master..